# iOS: UIPickerView user interaction disable didSelectRow still been call

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, uipickerview

I'm disable UIPicker:

```
[self.MyPicker setUserInteractionEnabled:false];
```

but didSelectRow still been call:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
```

Any of you knows how can I complete disable the UIPicker? or why setUserInteractionEnabled is not working ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: self.MyPicker is not nil ?

Comment: @azimov, No is not nil: <UIPickerView: 0x7fdf9b7152f0; frame = (0 915.5; 375 170); clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 100